nerd-icons not working with concat in Windows emacs
I'm using the below command to create a string with color-pallete icon which I want to use along with colorful-mode. But I'm not able to use the nerd-icons-faicon function with concat. It works fine with the insert function but not with concat.
I posted about this in colorful-mode as well - which you can find here for more details.
Problem
I can see that when I execute this command (C-c C-c) with insert I get the icon properly, but when I execute with concat the result is not rendered properly
using result
(insert (nerd-icons-faicon "nf-fae-palette_color") " ")


using concat
(concat (nerd-icons-faicon "nf-fae-palette_color") " ")


Additional details
I also asked for what the issue could be in this superuser post and found that the box that is currently being rendered with concat is in the Private Use Area. Does this mean this particular icon needs a specific font family?

Note that there a similar question regarding nerd-icons which suggests using M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts - which I already have done and I am able to see the icons properly in the modeline like below screenshot. I'm only facing this issue when I'm using the concat function.
modeline icons working fine:

